# Como retornar o últmo id inserido na tabela?

Tags: php, sql-server

Preciso pegar o id gerado, na última e recente inserção feita em uma tabela em SQLSRV, Mssql, usando PHP. Já estou conectando ao banco, usando o driver sqlsrv.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[ANALISE_CRITICA] (CC, NMANALISE, TXTOBS, VLRECEITACONT, VLRECEITABRUTA) 
         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

 $params = array($cc, $analiseCritica, $objetoExtra, $receitaContrato, $receitaBrutaMarco);
 $stmt = @sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
```

Comment: http://www.criarweb.com/artigos/181.php ;]
Outro modo seria você pegar algum identificador do último dado inserido, tipo CPF, Código Funcional, e fazer uma nova consulta retornando o ID daquele CPF

Comment: Você já sabe conectar ao banco e executar consultas no SQL Server com o PHP? Ou seja, está buscando somente a query, ou o caminho todo?

Comment: Especifique o driver que está usando. Se é o [mssql](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mssql.php) ou o [sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.sqlsrv.php)

Comment: Sim, está conectado ao banco.
Estou usando sqlsrv.

Comment: Apesar dos votos para fechar por este motivo, acho que a pergunta está clara. O que falta é mais detalhes da implementação atual.

Answer (score 2):

Segue um código para pegar o último Id gerado no SQL Server:

```
function sql_nextid()
{
    $result_id = @mssql_query('SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()');

    if ($result_id)
    {
        if ($row = @mssql_fetch_assoc($result_id))
        {
            @mssql_free_result($result_id);

            return $row['computed'];
        }

        @mssql_free_result($result_id);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Em MS Sql Server, a query para retornar o último ID gerado na sessão é:

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id
```

Veja a linha que adicionei ao seu código (último linha do bloco abaixo):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[ANALISE_CRITICA] (CC, NMANALISE, TXTOBS, VLRECEITACONT, VLRECEITABRUTA) 
         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

$params = array($cc, $analiseCritica, $objetoExtra, $receitaContrato, $receitaBrutaMarco);
$stmt = @sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);

$idRecenGerado = mssql_fetch_assoc(mssql_query("select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id"));
```

Aqui, `$idRecenGerado` contém o ID gerado durante a inserção em `ANALISE_CRITICA`.

Comment: Caffé, segui teus passos acima e não deu certo. sendo que quando eu clicava no botão pra salvar, era exibida essa linha "select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id" e a inserção não era feita.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[ANALISE_CRITICA] (CC, NMANALISE, TXTOBS, VLRECEITACONT) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
      $params = array($cc, $analiseCritica, $objetoExtra, $receitaContrato, $receitaBrutaMarco);
      $stmt = @sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
      "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id";
   
$query = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[AnaliseCriticaDataAssinatura] (idAnalise, dataAssinatura) VALUES (?,?)";
$idRecenGerado = @mssql_fetch_assoc(mssql_query("select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id"));
$paramsData = array($idRecenGerado, $dataContrato);
$stmtData = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $paramsData);

Comment: @GustavoSevero A primeira linha da minha resposta, `select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id`, não faz parte do código. Nela eu estou apenas descrevendo como isso funciona no SQL Server. O seu código é o segundo bloco da minha resposta.

Comment: Desculpe Caffé, mas mesmo tirando essa linha "select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id", não funcionou, até trancou a página depois que cliquei em salvar.

Comment: A chave para a solução do problema é o comando SQL que resgata o último ID gerado na sessão, `select SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Execute este comando e obtenha o resultado seguindo as mesmas práticas que você vem seguindo para executar os demais SELECTs.

Answer (score 1):

O driver [sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.sqlsrv.php) não tem nenhuma função nativa para recuperar o id do registro inserido. Nesse caso é preciso enviar duas consultas de uma vez só primeira o `INSERT` e a segunda um `SELECT` em [scope_identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) que retornará o valor do campo identity inserido.

[sqlsrv_next_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-next-result.php) retorna true caso exista algo(resultsets, número de linhas afetadas ou ainda outra saída) na instrução sql preocessada que é armazenada na variável `$stmt`. A cada chamada de `sqlsrv_next_result()` uma sql é desempilhada para obter seu retorno use `sqlsrv_fetch_*`

O código deve ficar dessa maneira:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[ANALISE_CRITICA]
        (CC, NMANALISE, TXTOBS, VLRECEITACONT, VLRECEITABRUTA) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS last_id";

$params = array($cc, $analiseCritica, $objetoExtra, 
                $receitaContrato, $receitaBrutaMarco);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params); //processa a consulta
$next_result = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt); //em caso sucesso desempilha a proxima sql(select) 

if($next_result){
    $item = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC); //obtem o resultado  
    echo $item['last_id'];
}
```

<sub>Obs: evite usar `@` no código elas mascaram as mensagens de erros e dificultam a detecção do problema, trate o erro.</sub>

Basedo em:

[SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850375/retrieve-the-id-of-an-inserted-record-php-ms-sql-server)

[manual - sqlsrv_next_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-next-result.php)

Comment: Perdeu, o $item não entrou na tabela.

Comment: @GustavoSevero, poderia colocara o código no comentário

Comment: se `$item` veio vazio é pq não tinha nenhuma consulta em `sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);` ou a consulta tinha algum erro. @GustavoSevero