# Carrinho de compra erro no array ao recuperar ultimo id sqlsrv_fetch_array 11- is not a valid ss_sqlsrv_stmt resource in

Tags: array, sql-server, select

Estou montando um carrinho de compras mas estou enfrentando o seguinte erro
que mencionei no título. O método recebe 2 parâmetro o $listaProdutos é um array como toda a informação da compra e o parâmetro $Total recebe a $_SESSION do valor total da compra. O Primeiro insert funciona de boa, que é a criação do pedido, depois faço um select para recuperar o último id do pedido para inserir os itens do pedido. Porém quando entra no if a variável $reg não recebe o valor da query e da o seguinte erro...

> sqlsrv_fetch_array(): 11 is not a valid ss_sqlsrv_stmt resource in

O que não entendo é porque ocasiona esse erro, porque não vejo erro no código, se puderem me ajudar desde já agradeço.

```
public function CriarVenda($listaProdutos, $Total){

        // criando venda
        $sql = "INSERT INTO CADPEDIDO(PED_DATA, VALORTOTAL)VALUES(?,?)";
        $params = array(date('Y-m-d'), $Total);
        $query = sqlsrv_query($this->con->Conecta(), $sql, $params);

        //resgatar última venda

        $sql = "SELECT MAX(CODIGO) FROM CADPEDIDO";
        $query = sqlsrv_query($this->con->Conecta(), $sql) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

        $ultimavenda = 0;

        if($reg = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){
            $ultimavenda = $reg[0];
        }

        foreach($listaProdutos as $p){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO CADITENSPEDIDO(ITEM_PEDIDO, ITEM_COD_PEDIDO,ITEM_QTD ITEM_PRECO)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
            $params = array($ultimavenda, $p->Codigo, $p->Qtd_comprado, $p->SubTotal);
            $query = sqlsrv_query($this->con->Conecta(), $sql, $params);

        }

 }
```

Comment: código é int? é identity?

Comment: tanto o codigo do pedido quanto do itens são identity

Comment: Pode pegar o último identity gerado [dessa forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37612/91)

Comment: então é o que estou fazendo SELECT MAX(CODIGO) FROM CADPEDIDO